# Как сделать выдвижной футер?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Никак не могу реализовать такой же футер, как на этом сайте (http://ritg.ru/). Подскажите, каким образом можно сделать такой футер.

Comment: Используйте [transition](https://davidwalsh.name/css-slide). Подробнее про это свойство можно почитать [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp). Беглый взгляд на пример с сайта говорит, что там просто подменяется свойство display (переключается с _block_ на _none_ и обратно) с помощью этого самого transition

Comment: `transition` не анимирует свойство `display`. На сайте-примере подвал скрывается/раскрывается методом `.slideToggle()` библиотеки `JQuery`

Answer (score 1):

Приблизительно так это реализовано на том сайте

```js
$('.footer__toggle').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('footer__toggle_active');
  $('.footer__inner').slideToggle();
})
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  min-height:100vh;
}
header{
  height:40px;
  flex:0 0 auto;
  background-color:#acd;
}
main{
  flex:1 1 auto;
  background-color:#cda;
}
footer{
  background-color:#dac;
  padding:40px 0 0;
  flex:0 0 auto;
  position:relative;
}
.footer__toggle{
  display:inline-block;
  position:Absolute;
  bottom:calc(100% - 20px);
  left:calc(50% - 20px);
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background-color:#dac;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:1.3;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:50%;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.footer__toggle:before{
  content:'\f106';
  font-family:fontAwesome;
}
.footer__toggle_active:before{
  content:'\f107';
}
.footer__inner{
  padding:10px 15px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>
<main></main>
<footer>
  <a href="#" class="footer__toggle"></a>
  <div class="footer__inner">
    <p>asda sas asdad fasd dasd asda sda sagssdasdagfsd</p>
    <p>asda sas asdad fasd dasd asda sda sagssdasdagfsd</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```